# Managing LinkButton with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a `LinkButton` called "Exit Chat" on the view.I embed `javascript` code into `OnClientClink=javascript:confirm('Are you sure you want to end the session?')`.However,I can't manage dialog box

When user click the OK button,view should be terminated.How can I do this?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Font-
    Bold="False" Font-Underline="False" 
    OnClientClick="javascript:confirm('Are you sure you want to end the session?')"
    ViewStateMode="Enabled" OnClick="LinkButton2_Click1" Text="Exit Chat">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

I wrote this code part but didnt work :(

```
if (LinkButton2.CommandName=="OK")
{
    MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = -1;
}
else if(LinkButton2.CommandName=="Cancel")
{
    MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
}
```

Comment: What specifically have you tried or researched so far?

Comment: if (LinkButton2.CommandName=="OK")
           {
               MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = -1;
           }
           else if(LinkButton2.CommandName=="Cancel")
           {
               MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
           }
       }

Comment: Might I suggest a Google search? Something along the lines of "ASP.NET controls confirmation box"?

Comment: When I click OK button,view screen should be closed,that's I want to do this but couldnt to do :S

Answer (score 0):

You can check the result of the confirm and then close the window if true.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
        CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"
        OnClientClick="return showConfirm();">
</asp:LinkButton>

<script>
function showConfirm()
{
   var ok = confirm('Are you certain you want to delete this product?');

   if (ok)
   {
      window.close();
   }
}
<script>
```

Comment: OnClientClink=javascript:confirm('Are you sure you want to end the session?') I have already have OK-Cancel button when I click LinkButton so no need to write ok variable

Comment: I just to manage OK-Cancel button,Clicking LinkButton I see OK-Cancel dialog screen,in here I cannot control OK-Cancel part of the dialog screen.