# LinkButton Designing with Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Managing LinkButton with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655275/managing-linkbutton-with-javascript)

I want to put LinkButton on MultiView control on Webform by manipulating function of LinkButton.LinkButton called "Exit Chat",when I click this button I need to see OK-Cancel dialog and when I select OK button,everything should be disappered on the MultiView.

How can I do this?(by using HTML and Javascript on Webform controls)

I tried to write javascript:confirm("*"); When I write this code I couldnt control OK-Cancel dialog screen :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do add a confirmation to LinkButton on client side as:

```
  <asp:LinkButton  OnClientClick="return confirm('are you sure ?...');" .../>
```

You can also call a javascript function as:

```
<script>
function ConfirmWithAction()
    {
        if(confirm('are you sure ?...'))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // do some more work....
            // redirect to an empty page as you ask
            window.location = "empty.html"
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<asp:LinkButton  OnClientClick="return ConfirmWithAction();" runat="server" ID="MyId" Text="click me" />
```

Comment: I already did,but after wrote this code part,I see OK-Cancel dialog box,I want to control OK-Cancel buttons,When I click OK view screen should be closed or redirecting "Empty Web Page".How can I do this?(with Javascript or others...)

Comment: @AhmetGüzel Then write some more javascript code and call it.

Comment: I know but how can ı manage OK-CANCEL dialog box????

Comment: When I click OK,I want to close my view screen...

Comment: @AhmetGüzel I have update the answer. Hopes that this helps you to move on.

Comment: thanks so useful but still some problems :)in the if statement how can I close my screen or redirect to empty web page?

Comment: @AhmetGüzel you can use the `window.location` to move to an empty page.

Comment: I wrote window.location.assign("http://...) but page just made postback and nothing changed :S

Comment: @AhmetGüzel If you get post back then the reason is that you get a javascript error, and the return false is not actually return to the linkubtton to stop it from post back. So check for the javascript errors.

Comment: now dialog box(Are you sure...) disapperad,browser just makes post back :S

Comment: @AhmetGüzel as I say you, you have javascript errors. Open the browser console to see them and fix them.